# WordPress Theme Creation

Tags: theme-development, themes

I have a HTML site that I would like to turn into a WordPress theme and I was wondering if people could pls point me to the best available Wordpress themes that can be used as a skeleton base for this HTML site?

I want something that represents the latest version of WordPress, and that is a good base to start from.

Any help/sites would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a bit too general for here, but try looking at the Twenty Eleven theme that ships with WordPress - it makes use of the latest functions.

Comment: Try "_s" from wp.com

Comment: Hi, don't believe it's too general as I was thinking of themes like Starkers and Chris Coyier's blank theme.

Comment: Then search for "theme framework" on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If modifying Twenty Eleven seems a bit daunting, you should try CSS-less themes like [BLANK](http://digwp.com/2010/02/blank-wordpress-theme/) by Chris Coyier. Otherwise, there are a handful of great starter themes that have all sorts of built-in functionality. The only down side is that these are sometimes just as much, if not more, difficult to learn since they have such a complex starter base. I would suggest reading through [this](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/wordpress-theme-frameworks-and-starting-resources/) post, as it lists several VERY good theme frameworks (especially Hybrid and Thematic)

Best of luck! And keep coming back if you have more questions. The community here is typically VERY good about getting questions answered.